# DAO is null when injected in REST service class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to inject a UserDao service into a rest service so that I can persist an entity. The problem that I'm facing is that this injected dao is never managed in spite of been annotated as @Statfull.
I've tried to make the dao a @Named @Requestscoped, with no result.
Also tried to use @EJB instead of @Inject at the rest service with no result.

I'm stuck!

**DAO SERVICE**

Here is the AbstractDao class:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
private final Class<T> clazz;

public AbstractDao() {
    clazz = null;
}
@Inject
EntityManager em;

public AbstractDao(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return em.find(clazz, id);
}

public void persist(final T entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    final CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(clazz);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaQuery.from(clazz));
    return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
}
```

The UserDao class:

```
@Stateful
public class UserDao extends AbstractDao<Useers>{

public UserDao() {
    super(Useers.class);
}
}
```

**REST SERVICE**

UserService Rest class:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

@Inject
UserDao userDao;

@POST
@Path("/adduser")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response addUser(UserPojo user) {
    Useers useers = new Useers();
    useers.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    useers.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    useers.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    userDao.persist(useers);
    System.out.println(user.getUsername());
    System.out.println("password "+user.getUsername());
    return Response.status(200).build();
}

}
```

**PARTIAL POM FILE**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Persistence jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>pojos</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
        of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
        as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
        JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**SERVER INFO**

```
18:12:59,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 

1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar")
18:12:59,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/luisalves/Documents/xxx/servers/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1_.Final/standalone/deployments
mar 11, 2019 6:12:59 PM org.jboss.threads.Version <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
18:12:59,993 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
18:13:00,137 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
mar 11, 2019 6:13:00 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final
mar 11, 2019 6:13:00 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.6.5.Final
mar 11, 2019 6:13:00 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.5.Final
mar 11, 2019 6:13:00 PM org.wildfly.security.Version <clinit>
INFO: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.7.0.Final
18:13:01,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
18:13:01,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar
18:13:01,712 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.3.Final
18:13:02,492 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
18:13:02,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar")
18:13:02,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
18:13:02,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
18:13:02,690 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:13:02,690 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 15.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 7.0.0.Final) started in 11389ms - Started 401 of 586 services (326 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2019-03-11 06:13:02,904] Artifact webapp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2019-03-11 06:13:02,904] Artifact serversideapi:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
18:13:03,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "webapp" (runtime-name: "webapp.war")
18:13:04,027 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
18:13:04,049 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0091: -ds.xml file deployments are deprecated. Support may be removed in a future version.
18:13:04,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/webappDS]
18:13:04,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/webappDS]
18:13:04,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'webapp#primary'
18:13:04,191 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
18:13:04,204 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment webapp.war
18:13:04,332 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
18:13:04,335 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
18:13:04,406 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.14.Final
18:13:04,604 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
18:13:04,995 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application.  In webapp.war either provide a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application or declare a servlet class in web.xml.
18:13:05,035 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 3.0.5 (Final)
18:13:05,375 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'webapp#primary'
18:13:06,346 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
18:13:06,359 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
18:13:06,451 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Envers integration enabled? : true
18:13:07,372 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-7) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
18:13:07,463 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
18:13:07,806 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
18:13:07,810 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider is annotated with @ApplicationScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
18:13:08,660 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2 for context '/webapp'
18:13:13,559 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/webapp' for server 'default-server'
18:13:13,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "webapp" (runtime-name : "webapp.war")
[2019-03-11 06:13:13,713] Artifact webapp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-03-11 06:13:13,713] Artifact webapp:war exploded: Deploy took 10,809 milliseconds
18:13:13,862 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "serversideapi" (runtime-name: "serversideapi.war")
18:13:14,978 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for serversideapi
18:13:15,041 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'serversideapi#serversideapi'
18:13:15,041 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: serversideapi
    ...]
18:13:15,092 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment serversideapi.war
18:13:15,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UserDao' in deployment unit 'deployment "serversideapi.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/serversideapi/UserDao!pt.xx.xxx.xxxxx.paj.daoapi.dao.UserDao
    java:app/serversideapi/UserDao!xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.dao.UserDao
    java:module/UserDao!xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.dao.UserDao
    ejb:serversideapi/UserDao!xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.dao.UserDao
    java:global/serversideapi/UserDao
    java:app/serversideapi/UserDao
    java:module/UserDao

18:13:15,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
18:13:15,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = serversideapi.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
18:13:15,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'serversideapi#serversideapi'
18:13:15,508 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
18:13:16,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
18:13:16,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Envers integration enabled? : true
18:13:18,339 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Visit_#auction; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,340 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Visit_#utilizador; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,340 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Visit_#id; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,342 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Bid_#auction; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,342 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Bid_#utilizador; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,350 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Auction_#minBind; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,350 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Auction_#utilizador; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,351 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Auction_#utilizadors; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,351 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Auction_#bids; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,351 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Auction_#visits; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,354 WARN  [org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.daoapi.entity.Bookmark_#id; this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel
18:13:18,467 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
18:13:18,783 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
18:13:18,795 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-2) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
18:13:19,414 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2 for context '/serversideapi'
18:13:21,391 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.restapi.services.ResteasyService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
18:13:21,409 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.restapi.services.UserService from Application class xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.paj.restapi.services.ResteasyService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
18:13:21,577 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/serversideapi' for server 'default-server'
18:13:21,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "serversideapi" (runtime-name : "serversideapi.war")
[2019-03-11 06:13:21,641] Artifact serversideapi:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-03-11 06:13:21,641] Artifact serversideapi:war exploded: Deploy took 18,737 milliseconds
```

Comment: What server and version are you using?

Comment: tried on Wildfly 13 Final and 15 Final

Comment: Please add the content of your server.log following the line containing: `WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment ...`

Comment: This is symptomatic of there being a competing JAX-RS implementation embedded in your WAR file. Please verify that there are no Jersey or RestEasy jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your application. Also, I see that you have an an extended `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class. Please remove any method bodies that you have declared as they are not necessary at this point.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your interest and your time. I found that the problem is with @ApplicationPath. I emptied it and the problem was solved! Like magic! After all there is magic in programming! Best wish's.

Answer (score 0):

UserDao is not a CDI Bean as it is annotated with an EJB annotation. [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic004.htm)

Have you set bean-discovery-mode to "all" in beans.xml? An example file can be found in [Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE). By default, i.e. without a beans.xml, CDI 1.2 does not inject EJBs or any other non-CDI beans (more info [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/default-cdi-enablement-in-java-ee-7)).

(you can upgrade the version to 1.2 in the beans element if you want to)

---

I do understand that you also tried CDI annotations `javax.inject.Named` and `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`. That should've worked if the `javax.ejb.Stateful` annotation was removed.

Comment: Hi Mikko please refer to my comments in my reply to @SteveC. Thanks for your input.

Comment: My bad. I'm glad you found the problem.